# Why just the creation of a TextField changes background of the Scene in javafx?

Tags: javafx, background, textfield, scene

I have a problem. In javafx app. I have a scene with a black background, but when I create a TextField, just create it, the background changes to white.

**I can't even change the background to black using:**

```
scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
```

It doesn't matter where I create the Textfield (at the beginning or end of the start function).

The code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage stage){
        TextField tf = new TextField();

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 600, 600, Color.BLACK);


        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Looks like if you add a node, it then expands the root node to fill the scene. I am not sure why this is happening. Set the color on the root node instead of the scene.

Comment: @Sedrick The root node is always expanded to fill the scene. It’s just transparent of Modena.css is not applied, and has the color scene in the second screenshot if modena.css is applied.

Comment: Thanks, for clearing that up. @James_D.